# UIbutton selected state

Tags: xcode, button, uibutton, selected

I am making an app with 20 questions, and you can answer Yes or No with the buttons for each questions. so I using 40 buttons.
when I clic the YES button it should remain selected (there is a default image and selected image), if I click NO it should remain selected and deselected the YESbutton.
this is the code i am using. it works with 2 buttons, but it does not work with more buttons.

.h

```
IBOutlet UIButton *bot2;
IBOutlet UIButton *bot3;
IBOutlet UIButton *bot4;
IBOutlet UIButton *bot5;
```

40in total
}

```
-(IBAction)a:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)b:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)c:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)d:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)e:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)f:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)g:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)h:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)i:(id)sender;
```

.....40 in total

```
@end
```

.m

```
-(IBAction)a:(id)sender
{
    if (ButtonSelected == 0)
    {
    [bot2 setSelected:YES];
    ButtonSelected = 1;

    }
    else
    {
    [bot2 setSelected:NO];
            ButtonSelected = 0;
    }
}


-(IBAction)b:(id)sender
{
    if (ButtonSelected == 0)
    {
        [bot3 setSelected:YES];
        ButtonSelected = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        [bot3 setSelected:NO];
        ButtonSelected = 0;
    }
}
-(IBAction)c:(id)sender
{
    if (ButtonSelected == 0)
    {
        [bot4 setSelected:YES];
        ButtonSelected = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        [bot4 setSelected:NO];
        ButtonSelected = 0;
    }
}
```

ecc eccc......

Comment: You realize that you can use *one* IBAction for multiple buttons?

Comment: Hi Sam, the problem is: Yes and No buttons should work together, for example (button but2 is linked to ibaction a and b, button but3 to ibaction a and b), but the other Yes and No button should have ibaction c and d) right?

Comment: here you can see the original code, if anyone can help me..  http://dl.dropbox.com/u/19622479/ipadapp%202%202%202.zip

Answer (score 2):

For this scenario, it is probably better to use instances of UISegmentedControl for each Yes/No combo.

Comment: Or if it's just Yes/No (or True/False or On/Off, etc), you could use UISwitches.